# Why is rust process causing terminal errors on Ctrl+C?

Tags: terminal, rust

My program has a `process::Command` spawned and waited. In that process is a bash command running a command that will also wait for an exit signal to stop the process. For example,

```rust
let shell = "bash";

Command::new(shell)
  .arg("-c")
  .arg("watch command") // watch command won't stop until it gets a Ctrl+C
  .spawn()
  .unwrap();
  .wait()
  .unwrap();
```

During the process is running, if I type `Ctrl+C` I get two questions about whether to terminate the process or not (Y/N) consequently. If I just type `Ctrl+C` for just a few more times, the process will exit. But when I chose to answer the question with Y or N, the terminal will break. I can't type commands, Enter keys won't work, cannot even exit from the terminal. The new commands I type will replace the current texts on the terminal, and I can even delete the terminal texts like a text editor.

I don't know what was causing the error. Am I doing something wrong? How do I add an event listener that will listen for `Ctrl+C` command and exit the process completely on the event?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Linux, MacOS, WSL? And which terminal? The answer is likely to depend on those…

Comment: On windows, I've tested on both Bash and PowerShell, results are pretty much the same.

Comment: Can you update your code to not run `-c watch command` and test that it's forwarding stdin correctly? (you can write in the bash shell and run commands). It sounds like this is just a Windows oddity since it works fine for me on Linux.

Comment: C-c straight closes everything for me but I'd guess something (either term or shell) intercepts the C-c and prompts for termination and if you accept it kills the subprocess in such a way that `watch` doesn't get to clean up the terminal: `watch` uses curses, and curses famously messes up terminals if not properly shut down. Using `reset` or `ssty sane` followed by `clear` should clean up the broken terminal (you may want / need to use Ctrl+J to confirm either the `reset` or the `stty sane` as the return key might just print `^M`).

Comment: Ctrl-C is messed up on Windows in general; it's specific to Rust.